# Created commerce customers through CustomerServiceProvider not found in engine with GetCustomerCommand

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm new to `Sitecore` so I could have missed something obvious, but here goes.
We have Commerce engine and API projects. In API, we create a user with `CustomerServiceProvider`:

```
var request = new CreateUserRequest(string.Format("extranet\\{0}", userName), password, email, shopName);
var result = _customerServiceProvider.CreateUser(request);
```

However, when creating customers this way they can not be found in the Engine project when using the
built-in GetCustomerCommand. When I create a customer using the postman template instead `(CustomersAPISamples -> Do Actions -> Add Customer)`,
it's found with no problems with `GetCustomerCommand`.

When using the postman template for getting all customers `(CustomersAPISamples -> Lists -> Customers)`, it only lists customers created through the add customer postman template.

Regardless of using CustomerServiceProvider or using postman, the entities show up in the database tables `sitecore_commerce_storage.CustomersEntity` and `CustomerEntities` fine.

They also look identical except IDs, personal details and CreatedBy, UpdatedBy which are missing in the entity created by CustomerServiceProvider (I diffed the entity JSON).

The interesting thing to note is that when creating a user through CustomerServiceProvider, it does return `Success: false`, even though it does create the customer entity. There are no system messages.

So how come I can't find some of my customers with the GetCustomerCommand?
I thought it would basically just search the entity tables, but apparently it does something more/else. How does it work?

Comment: Hi, which version of sitecore commerce you are using?

Comment: @VipinBanka Sorry, that should've been in the post. Sitecore 9.2. Sitecore.Commerce.Core 4.0.72. Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Customers 4.0.16 (latest).

Comment: please check that you have customer entity id entry in [CustomersLists] table for list name "List-CUSTOMERS-ByDate"

Comment: @VipinBanka yes, the entity is in CustomersLists as well. https://imgur.com/E75kvrH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is now solved.

It turned out it was a misconfigured environment. Customers created from our API were placed under a blank environment in Sitecore Experience Commerce.

For anyone else with the same problem, make sure to configure your "defaultEnvironment" in `wwwroot\sc92.local\App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config`.

For other similar issues it might also help to clear the caches and clean / re-bootstrap and re-initialize your environments in the SitecoreCommerce_DevOps Postman templates.